# How to install the OpenCart 2.3 extension?

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to install an extension of the Bling platform in my OpenCart application, I know they have forum, but the material is scarce. So I came here. I downloaded the package and followed the steps of the installation, extracted the files and placed in the folder indicated by the documentation.

[image]

So I went to OpenCart to install the extension, but I did not find the file there, do I need to update something? Do I need to change the structuring of folders? If anyone can help me, I'll be happy.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't see the extension you are describing in the marketplace - please put a link to it so I can see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info here:
[Module Development OpenCart](http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/)

Answer (score 0):

Log into your OpenCart Dashboard.
Go to Extensions > Product Feeds.
Click on “Install” next to the “Google Site Map” product feed name.
Click “Edit” and then change the status to “Enabled”
Copy the “Data Feed URL” and click “Save"